# Batch update in Postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I needed `UPSERT` functionality in Postgres. Since Postgres does not support this natively, I wrote a function which does that (tries to update, if no row was updated then inserts)

This is the template for the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109198/681671

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_db(key INT, data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE db SET b = data WHERE a = key;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- not there, so try to insert the key
        -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently,
        -- we could get a unique-key failure
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES (key, data);
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT merge_db(1, 'david');
```

I am using Spring JDBC template. This select statement (in its parameterized form) and an array of objects is what I pass to the the batchUpdate method of JDBCTemplate.

I get this exception:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
```

I suspect it is because of use of `SELECT`.

I know I can use Callable in a loop but that would make the app very chatty and I/O latency will make it very slow.

How is batch upsert done in Postgres using Spring JDBC / raw JDBC?

I am using Postgresql 9.1.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20upsert

Comment: @CraigRinger: Thanks will try that. But still looking for a confirmation that multiple parameterized calls to a procedure cannot be batched when using JDBC + Postgres. I saw addBatch method of Statement interface and it does something similar to what I want but does it not accept parameters. One has to serialize the parameters in application code and provide a SQL string. There are many parameters  and escaping each may be prone to error.

Comment: Could you show us how are you calling the function from Java?

Answer (score 7):

Batch upsert is done in PostgreSQL by:

- Beginning a transaction
- Creating a `TEMPORARY` table
- Populating it using JDBC batched `INSERT` or (preferably) by using the `COPY` API provided by the PgJDBC driver
- `LOCK`ing the real destination table `IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`, which allows only `SELECT`s from other transactions to continue.
- Doing an `UPDATE ... FROM` to update existing rows
- Doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM real_table WHERE ...)` to add rows that aren't already in `real_table`
- `COMMIT`ing the transaction

If multiple transactions attempt to do this they'll land up getting serialised on the table lock. An upsert isn't ever going to be a concurrency-friendly operation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about postgres in particular, but my usual method is as follows :

- do the insert
- if it fails with unique_violation, do an update

I do it this way so that it minimizes locks on the table, and guards against race conditions.

Of course, it'll only work if the table you are inserting into has a unique constraint on columns other than the primary key.